# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class x.y.z.HibernateUtil after hibernate-search upgraded from 4.5.1.Final to 5.5.5.Final

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I recently updated my application to use hibernate-search 5.5.5.Final instead of 4.5.1. The problem is, during run time it is giving me java.lang.NoClassDefFound for not being able to initialize my HibernateUtil class. Following is the fullStackTrace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class x.y.z.util.HibernateUtil
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at x.y.z.searchresult_421_aets.SearchHitGenerator_421_Aets.getSearchHits(SearchHitGenerator_421_Aets.java:84)
at x.y.z.searchresult_421_aets.SearchHitGenerator_421_Aets.call(SearchHitGenerator_421_Aets.java:116)
at x.y.z.searchresult_421_aets.SearchHitGenerator_421_Aets.call(SearchHitGenerator_421_Aets.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class x.y.z.util.HibernateUtil
at x.y.z.a421_aets_search_hit_provider.GoARIS_A421_Vw_SearchHitProvider.getGoARIS_A421_Vw_HitList(GoARIS_A421_Vw_SearchHitProvider.java:41)
at x.y.z.a421_aets_search_hit_provider.GoARIS_A421_Vw_SearchHitProvider.call(GoARIS_A421_Vw_SearchHitProvider.java:194)
at x.y.z.a421_aets_search_hit_provider.GoARIS_A421_Vw_SearchHitProvider.call(GoARIS_A421_Vw_SearchHitProvider.java:1)
... 4 more
```

In the method inside HibernateUtil class as shown below, my error comes from **sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);**

```
private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory()
            throws HibernateException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernateSearch.cfg.xml");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Following is the only I am using for any hibernate related dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, the only other dependency that could have overridden hibernate ORM that I can think of is jasperReport:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For oracle driver, I am using:
    
        com.hynnet
        oracle-driver-ojdbc6
        12.1.0.1

It is taking quite a while to debug this, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Certainly a dependency configuration problem. I'd verify if any other of your dependencies is possibly overriding the Hibernate ORM version against the one which Hibernate Search would want? If you could include the full stacktrace that might give me some more clues.

Comment: @Sanne Thank you for your response. I have added the fullStrackTrace + maven dependency that could have overridden Hibernate ORM

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was not notified of the update. I checked the jasperreports dependency: it doesn't seem problematic. Rather than guessing, use the maven reporting capabilities to tell you which versions are being used? For example `mvn dependency:tree`, or import the project in an IDE and see which versions you're getting.

Comment: @Sanne jasperReport was not the problem. I had problem with multiple version of lucene which I resolved. But I am still getting error. I have isolated the error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899973/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-x-y-z-hibernateutil-a is my attempt to resolve the problem in isolation. After I resolve it, I will come back to resolving it. You can see my updates on that issues for right now.

Comment: I have attached a test case in HSEARCH-2530 in which I have mentioned I was not able to index a table with 5.5.Final but was able to do so with 5.3.  I was able to index with oracle database but in this case I was using SQLite.